# Shader code for placing 5 smaller images in different offsets on a larger base image

Tags: unity, shaders

I'm trying to texture atlas in realtime, with 5 smaller texture2Ds to be placed on a larger base texture2D...

This shader code only shows the first texture and not the others -  and even though it is smaller, seems to scale to size of base texture.

Is what I am trying to do possible with shaders? How do we fix / do this?

````
Shader "Custom/OverlayShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _OverlayTex0 ("Overlay Texture 0", 2D) = "white" {}
        _OverlayTex1 ("Overlay Texture 1", 2D) = "white" {}
        _OverlayTex2 ("Overlay Texture 2", 2D) = "white" {}
        _OverlayTex3 ("Overlay Texture 3", 2D) = "white" {}
        _OverlayTex4 ("Overlay Texture 4", 2D) = "white" {}
        _OverlayPos0 ("Overlay Position 0", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
        _OverlayPos1 ("Overlay Position 1", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
        _OverlayPos2 ("Overlay Position 2", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
        _OverlayPos3 ("Overlay Position 3", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
        _OverlayPos4 ("Overlay Position 4", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
        _OverlayAspectRatio0 ("Overlay Aspect Ratio 0", float) = 1.0
        _OverlayAspectRatio1 ("Overlay Aspect Ratio 1", float) = 1.0
        _OverlayAspectRatio2 ("Overlay Aspect Ratio 2", float) = 1.0
        _OverlayAspectRatio3 ("Overlay Aspect Ratio 3", float) = 1.0
        _OverlayAspectRatio4 ("Overlay Aspect Ratio 4", float) = 1.0
        _MainAspectRatio ("Main Texture Aspect Ratio", float) = 1.0
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            sampler2D _OverlayTex0;
            sampler2D _OverlayTex1;
            sampler2D _OverlayTex2;
            sampler2D _OverlayTex3;
            sampler2D _OverlayTex4;
            float4 _OverlayPos0;
            float4 _OverlayPos1;
            float4 _OverlayPos2;
            float4 _OverlayPos3;
            float4 _OverlayPos4;
            float _OverlayAspectRatio0;
            float _OverlayAspectRatio1;
            float _OverlayAspectRatio2;
            float _OverlayAspectRatio3;
            float _OverlayAspectRatio4;
            float _MainAspectRatio;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 mainColor = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                fixed4 overlayColor0 = tex2D(_OverlayTex0, (i.uv - _OverlayPos0.xy) * (_OverlayAspectRatio0 / _MainAspectRatio));
                fixed4 overlayColor1 = tex2D(_OverlayTex1, (i.uv - _OverlayPos1.xy) * (_OverlayAspectRatio1 / _MainAspectRatio));
                fixed4 overlayColor2 = tex2D(_OverlayTex2, (i.uv - _OverlayPos2.xy) * (_OverlayAspectRatio2 / _MainAspectRatio));
fixed4 overlayColor3 = tex2D(_OverlayTex3, (i.uv - _OverlayPos3.xy) * (_OverlayAspectRatio3 / _MainAspectRatio));
fixed4 overlayColor4 = tex2D(_OverlayTex4, (i.uv - _OverlayPos4.xy) * (_OverlayAspectRatio4 / _MainAspectRatio));
fixed4 overlayColor = overlayColor0.a > 0 ? overlayColor0 : (overlayColor1.a > 0 ? overlayColor1 : (overlayColor2.a > 0 ? overlayColor2 : (overlayColor3.a > 0 ? overlayColor3 : (overlayColor4.a > 0 ? overlayColor4 : mainColor))));
return overlayColor;
}
ENDCG
}
}
}

```
````

Comment: Are these 5 images arranged so as to not overlap? If so, you can probably combine them more efficiently with `Graphics.CopyTexture`. This does a direct GPU-side block copy of just the rectangle of pixels covered by the source at a given offset, rather than invoking complex shader logic for every pixel in the destination texture, so it will scale better as you increase the number of images in your atlas.

Comment: They might overlap, but masks are used

Comment: Then you may want to use `Graphics.Blit`, which can handle blending the masks rather than replacing whole rectangles.

Comment: Okay... tried that but no go https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/205580/how-do-you-efficiently-place-smaller-textures-into-a-larger-texture