# How do you efficiently place smaller textures into a larger texture?

Tags: unity, texture-atlas

(Edit - this seems to work now *except trying to read render texture to Texture2D to save it does not seem to update with any of the overlays, just shows the base... i wonder if this is because the pixel size of the baseTexture may be larger than that of the screen size*

Edit: this seems to be a Unity 2021 bug in writing render texture to texture2D)

How do you efficiently place smaller textures into a larger texture?

Approach so far [(after being advised not to do the shader approach)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/205555/shader-code-for-placing-5-smaller-images-in-different-offsets-on-a-larger-base-i?noredirect=1#comment374721_205555).

Trying to place (resized) smaller textures `overlayTextures` with positions specified in `overlayPositions` and resultant dimensions in `overlayWH` on top of a `baseTexture`

Using `Graphics.Bilt` generates a resulting gray texture. Swapping out to a GL.Clear white texture, yields a black texture...

[TextureScale.cs is here](https://gist.github.com/gszauer/7799899).

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TexturePlacer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D baseTexture;
    public Texture2D[] overlayTextures;
    public Vector2[] overlayPositions;
    public Vector2[] overlayWH;
    public Material material;

    void Start()
    { 
        TextureFormat format = TextureFormat.RGBA32;

        // Resize each overlay texture and convert it to the same format as the first overlay texture
        for (int i = 0; i < overlayPositions.Length; i++)
        {
            TextureScale.Bilinear(overlayTextures[i], (int)overlayWH[i].x, (int)overlayWH[i].y);

            // Create a new texture with the same format as the first overlay texture
            Texture2D newt = new Texture2D(overlayTextures[i].width, overlayTextures[i].height, format, false);

            // Copy the pixel data from the original texture to the new one
            newt.SetPixels(overlayTextures[i].GetPixels());
            newt.Apply();

            // Replace the original texture with the new one
            overlayTextures[i] = newt;

            //overlayPositions[i].y = baseTexture.height - overlayPositions[i].y;
        }
       
        if (overlayTextures.Length == 0 || overlayPositions.Length == 0 || overlayWH.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Overlay textures, positions, or sizes are not specified.");
            return;
        }

        if (overlayTextures.Length != overlayPositions.Length || overlayTextures.Length != overlayWH.Length)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Each overlay texture needs a corresponding position and width/height.");
            return;
        } 
        // Create a new base texture with the same format as the first overlay texture
        baseTexture = new Texture2D(baseTexture.width, baseTexture.height, format, false);

        // Create a temporary RenderTexture to work on
        RenderTexture rt = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(baseTexture.width, baseTexture.height);
         Graphics.Blit(baseTexture, rt);
        // Fill the render texture with a solid color
       // GL.Clear(true, true, Color.white);


        // Set the active RenderTexture to the temporary one we just created
        RenderTexture previous = RenderTexture.active;
        RenderTexture.active = rt;

        // Copy each overlay texture onto the base texture
        for (int i = 0; i < overlayTextures.Length; i++)
        {
            Texture2D overlayTexture = overlayTextures[i];
            Vector2 position = overlayPositions[i];
            Vector2 size = overlayWH[i];

            // Check if the overlay texture fits within the base texture
            if (position.x + size.x > baseTexture.width || position.y + size.y > baseTexture.height)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Overlay texture " + i + " exceeds the base texture boundaries.");
                continue;
            }
            // Check if the overlay texture has the same format as the first overlay texture
            if (overlayTexture.format != format)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Overlay texture " + i + " has a different format from the first overlay texture.");
                continue;
            }

            // Create a temporary texture to resize the overlay texture
            Texture2D tempTexture = new Texture2D((int)size.x, (int)size.y, format, false);
            Graphics.CopyTexture(overlayTexture, tempTexture);

            // Copy the resized overlay texture onto the base texture
            Graphics.CopyTexture(tempTexture, 0, 0, 0, 0, tempTexture.width, tempTexture.height, rt, 0, 0, (int)position.x, (int)position.y);
        }

        // Create a new texture and copy the RenderTexture image to it
        Texture2D newTexture = new Texture2D(baseTexture.width, baseTexture.height, format, false);
        newTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, rt.width, rt.height), 0, 0);
        newTexture.Apply();

        // Set the active RenderTexture back to the previous one
        RenderTexture.active = previous;

        // Release the temporary RenderTexture
       // RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(rt);

        // Use the new texture (for example, assign it to a material)
        material.mainTexture = newTexture;
    }
}
```